# How to call a function in ASM without call or jump?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I am currently trying to call this function called "super_secret_function", which is defined outside of main in file main.c. I am using ASM, and cannot use jmp or call to reach this "super_secret_function". Inside of main is a function called stack_hack, which is the function that I am able to manipulate to change addresses to reach the super secret function.

Using GDB I have been able to determine addresses of "super_secret_function", and successfully call it by jmping to it from the function. How can I manipulate the return value of the pointer to return back to that address?

```
.globl stack_hack

stack_hack: 
pushq  %rbp       # push the base pointer on the stack
movq  %rsp, %rbp  # move the previous stack pointer to the new base poi

##MyCode
movq  $0x00000000004005b4, %rbp
jmp   *%rbp
##EndMyCode 

movq %rbp, %rsp   # move the stack pointer to the base pointer
popq %rbp         # pop the base pointer and load it into %rbp
ret               # pop the instruction pointer into %rip
```

Comment: What is a "return value of a pointer"?

Comment: As a bare minimum, `ret` takes a value from the stack and uses it to change the IP. How can you change whats on the stack, can this be leveraged to take you _to_ somewhere, instead of _back from_ somewhere? Hint: it's actually not as hard as you think. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I moved the destination into %rax, and after popping rbp off, i then pushed %rax onto the stack and returned

Comment: Don't do this. It screws up the return address predictor stack and will tank your performance. Just use a call/jmp instruction. The CPU knows what that means and it is optimized for that scenario.

Comment: @RaymondChen I'm pretty sure this is a homework assignment, not a practical exercise; performance is most likely not a concern. :)

Comment: @duskwuff The Tour says that SO is for "**practical**, detailed questions". If this is a homework assignment, the OP may be better served by asking the instructor. (At a minimum, OP needs to credit this web site in the assignment.)

Answer (score 4):

Since this sounds like a homework assignment, I won't give you an exact answer, but I'll try to point you in the right direction.

You said you can't use `jmp` or `call`, but the `ret` at the end of the function also updates the program counter. How can you influence the value it updates the program counter to?

Comment: TBH I am extremely stuck. I have tried putting %rbp into %rsp however that resulted in a failure as well.

Comment: 1) Where does the `ret` at the end of the function get its value from? 2) How can you influence this? (Hint: The first question is answered in your code listing.)

Comment: It gets the value rax and puts it into rip

Comment: No, that's not what `ret` does. Read the comment and try again.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding     ret. 

It should return to the value of the old stack pointer?

Comment: And where does it get that old value from?

Answer (score 1):

Note your own example code and it's comment:

```
        ret       # pop the instruction pointer into %rip
```

where is the data is that will be popped into %rip by the ret instruction?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed after loading the address in %rax, and after popping %rbp before ret I pushed %rax onto the stack